# IDAPython with PyCharm throws: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ida_hexrays'"

Tags: python, pycharm, ida

I want to use PyCharm with IDAPython. I setup the Python Interpreter by adding the following path to the "Interpreter Paths":

```
C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 7.7\python\3
```

After that, it recognize the modules `idaapi` and `idautils` which is a good sign.

I wrote a simple scripts to test it:

```
import idaapi
import idautils

filename = idaapi.get_input_file_path()
```

I set a breakpoint on the `filename...` row and it failed with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 7.7\python\3\ida_hexrays.py", line 12, in <module>
    import _ida_hexrays
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ida_hexrays'
```

It doesn't recognize the modules `_ida_hexrays`. How can I make it work?
I see that there is a file: `C:\Program Files\IDA Pro 7.7\python\3\ida_64\_ida_hexrays.pyd`.

In the `ida_hexrays.py` it throws the error when it try to import it like that:

```
# Import the low-level C/C++ module
if __package__ or "." in __name__:
    from . import _ida_hexrays
else:
    import _ida_hexrays
```

Comment: As far as I know IDAPython is only available within IDA. You can use PyCharm to write Python code that runs in IDA but you can't actually run the code.

Comment: You can check this out https://github.com/overfl0/IDAPython-pycharm-setup